Keycloak with SpringBoot
I'm trying to configure a little test application which is based on SpringBoot/Vaadin and Kotlin to integrate with Keycloak.
I have an example app which I've adapted. This app uses the following settings in the application.yml to configure the Keycloak client and endpoints:
spring:
  mustache:
    check-template-location: false
  application:
    name: HelloVaadin
  devtools:
    restart:
      poll-interval: 2s
      quiet-period: 1s
  security:
    oauth2.client.registration.keycloak:
      client-id: vaadin-client
      authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
      scope: openid
      client-secret: UrRh3a9CQD25OSmFDvulY7btApvm8b74
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:7979/realms/vaadin-demo
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
            token-uri: http://localhost:7979/realms/vaadin-demo/protocol/openid-connect/token

I would like to used a more code based configuration using a ClientRegistrationRepository with a ClientRegistration. Unfortunately I have to configure some more properties with the ClientRegistration, like this:
return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("vaadin-client")
    .clientId("vaadin-client")
    .scope("openid")
    .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST)
    .clientSecret("UrRh3a9CQD25OSmFDvulY7btApvm8b74")
    .issuerUri("http://localhost:7979/realms/vaadin-demo")
    .redirectUri("http://localhost:8080/redirect")
    .authorizationUri("http://localhost:7979/realms/vaadin-demo/protocol/openid-connect/auth")
    .tokenUri("http://localhost:7979/realms/vaadin-demo/protocol/openid-connect/token")
    .userNameAttributeName("preferred_username")
    .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
    .build()

When I want to authorise as a user I get redirect to the Keycloak-Login-page where I can provide Username and Password but my GrantedAuthoritiesMapper - Bean does not get called anymore so I cannot extract the roles which then does not allow me to access pages which check for certain roles.
It all works with the YAML-Based configuration.
I've tried certain things but nothing seems to work.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Best Regards,
Frank

It's hard to offer specific advice here, as this issue is very specialized. My only suggestion is to check if the SSO-kit could be helpful for you, as it simplifies integration with Keycloak  greatly:
https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/tools/sso/integrations/keycloak.
The downside is that it is not free if you want to use it in production, but perhaps your budget can allow this, and you would also get support from Vaadin developers (can create tickets for fix if you encounter something and so). Moreover, many hiccups along the way might be handled by this kit as well.

Another idea is to provide your entire repository (on GitHub); perhaps a security expert or someone who has encountered this issue can help. Additionally, you could check the Vaadin forum for free help. Many Vaadin developers are very active there, and there is a high chance you will receive some kind of answer sooner than here.
